# Arrays inside a PHP function

Tags: php

I'm trying to access an arrays data from inside a function but keep getting the error: Undefined varaible: status. Any idea how to correct this?

```
<?php

$state = 'New York';

function state_values($state){
    switch ($state) {
        case 'New York':
            echo "State is $state";
            $status = array("abbr" => "NY", "code" => "03");
            return $status;
            break;
        case 'California':
            echo "State is $state";
            $status = array("abbr" => "CA", "code" => "06");
            return $status;
            break;
        case 'Washington':
            echo "State is $state";
            $status = array("abbr" => "WA", "code" => "05");
            return $status;
            break;
    }
}

# Call the function
state_values($state);


echo $status['abbr'];
echo $status['code'];


?>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to store the return value from your function call in a variable

```
$answer = state_values($state);

echo $answer["abbr"];

echo $answer["code"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `$status` is being declared as a local variable in the function `state_values`, it's not accessible from outside the function unless you save the returned value to another variable.

Your code below should read as follows in order to capture the returned `$status` variable.

```
$status = state_values($state);

echo $status['abbr'];
echo $status['code'];
```

The PHP documentation has a very nice section on [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

---

While it's not a very good way to handle it, you *could* do it using a global variable for `$status` like this:

```
$state = 'New York';
$status = array();

function state_values($state){
    global $status;

    switch ($state) {
        case 'New York':
            echo "State is $state";
            $status = array("abbr" => "NY", "code" => "03");
            break;
        case 'California':
            echo "State is $state";
            $status = array("abbr" => "CA", "code" => "06");
            break;
        case 'Washington':
            echo "State is $state";
            $status = array("abbr" => "WA", "code" => "05");
            break;
    }
}

# Call the function
state_values($state);

echo $status['abbr'];
echo $status['code'];
```

In the above, we declare `$status` **outside** the function, then specify **inside** the function that `$status` is a global variable.  Any changes to `$status` that happen during the call to `state_values` change the global copy of the variable.

Like I said though, ***this makes for confusing & hard to maintain code so your initial approach is better.***  The above is more to illustrate how global variables work.

Comment: -1 please don't even talk about globals to someone who is clearly not prepared to hear the answer without messing up

Comment: I still think it's a valid point to make for future readers of this question.  But I've tried to make it more clear that I think the global approach is not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning the value from the function into a variable.

```
$status = state_values($state);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sine it returns value, you have to give value to a variable too.

`$status = state_values($state);` would do it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have to assign the return value, like:

```
$status = state_values($state);
```

The variable `$status` you declared **in** the function is only accessible from *inside* the function, **not** the *outside* code.

You are not accessing the array from inside the function! You only define it there.

---

Btw, you can improve your function by just returning the array at the end of the function and echoing just once (this applies to the [DRY-principle (Don't Repeat Yourself)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRY)):

```
function state_values($state){
    echo "State is $state";

    // initialize the variable with an empty array
    $status = array();

    switch ($state) {
        case 'New York':
            $status = array("abbr" => "NY", "code" => "03");
            break;
        case 'California':
            $status = array("abbr" => "CA", "code" => "06");
            break;
        case 'Washington':
            $status = array("abbr" => "WA", "code" => "05");
            break;
    }
    return $status;
}
```

**Update:**

With regard to the comments: Of course there are various ways to make the function even nicer, e.g. using a lookup table:

```
//...
$states = array('New York' => array("NY","03"),
                'California' => array("CA","06"),
                'Washington' => array("WA","05"));

if(isset($states[$state])) {
    return array_combine(array('abbr', 'code'), $states[$state]);
}
return array();
//..
```

But that was not the question ;)

Comment: I'd say even this one is not dry enough ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have to say that whole concept is wrong.
It should be not a function or at least not in this form.

```
$state = 'New York';

function state_values($state){
  return dbgetrow("SELECT * FROM states WHERE name = %s",$state);
}
$status = state_values($state);
echo "State is $state, abbr is ".$status['abbr'];
```

or at least make it just array

```
$state_values = array(
   'New York' => array("abbr" => "NY", "code" => "03"),
   'California' => array("abbr" => "CA", "code" => "06"),
   'Washington' => array("abbr" => "WA", "code" => "05"),
);

echo $state_values[$state]['abbr'];
```

Comment: @stereofrog it's all right brotha. I have time to spare for good advice. no prob. cheers :)

Comment: @stereofrog Yeah, exactly. Don't be too anxious of time or efforts I spent. I have a better solution for the problem the OP face, and I am glad to share. A good answer always worth, isn't it? May be not the OP but someone else will learn from my answer a better practice. Don't you think there is something bad with it?